# How to make Table header column perfectly align with the data columns in Table Viewer?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, swt, jface, wizard, tableviewer

I noticed that header columns are not perfectly aligned with the columns which hold values.

[image]

A random screenshot taken from [here](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJFaceTable/article.html)

[image]

Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: There is no control over this, it is up to the native control that SWT uses on your platform. You can always turn lines off so you don't see the issue.

Comment: Thanks Greg. Can you please guide on how to turn off those lines?

Comment: There is Table.setLinesVisible for the table lines. TableColumn.setResizable may change the header lines - platform dependent.

Comment: Thanks Greg. I want only the  lines separating the header columns to be turned off only and not the table lines. Is that possible?

Comment: There is no direct control of that. On some platforms TableColumn.setResizable and setMoveable may change the look of the header. If you have more complex requirements you might look at [Eclipse NatTable](https://www.eclipse.org/nattable/) [tag:nattable].